# Set of index page numbers need to be set in ascending order through python (page number contain with figure and note citation)

Tags: python

Set of index page numbers need to be set in ascending order through python

may index page number contains with figure and note citation like `10f, 10n6` (unformatted number), and index page number enclosed with xml tag like `10'

I need the below output through python.

`Input = 5, 8, 10, 15f, 10f, 16-17n2, 15-17, 25, 27f, 27, 20, 27n6, n7, 40f, 41f, 40-45, 50, 60, 74, 90-98, 42-43n6, 44-45f, 92-93f`

`Output = 5, 8, 10, 10f, 15f, 15-17, 16-17n2, 20, 25, 27, 27f, 27n6, n7, 40f, 40-45, 41f, 42-43n6, 44-45f, 50, 60, 74, 90-98, 92-93f`

XML Structure Input

`<nav-pointer id="c0.25">5</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c1.p03">8</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c1.p2">10</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c3.p2">15f</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c4.p80">10f</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c4.p85">16</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c4.p87">17n2</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c4.p98">15</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c5">17</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p78">25</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p79">27f</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p82">27</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p83">20</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p84">27n6, n7</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p88">40f</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p89">41f</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p90">40</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c5.p92">45</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p8">50</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p10">60</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p36">74</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p56">90</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c6.p66">98</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p96">42</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c6.p104">43n6</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p109">44</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c6.p106">45f</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p8s">92</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c6.p8adaew">93f</nav-pointer>`

XML Structure Output

`<nav-pointer id="c0.25">5</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c1.p03">8</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c1.p2">10</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c4.p80">10f</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c3.p2">15f</nav-pointer>,  <nav-pointer id="c4.p98">15</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c5">17</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c4.p85">16</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c4.p87">17n2</nav-pointer>,  <nav-pointer id="c5.p83">20</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p78">25</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p82">27</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p79">27f</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p84">27n6, n7</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p88">40f</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p90">40</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c5.p92">45</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c5.p89">41f</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p96">42</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c6.p104">43n6</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p109">44</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c6.p106">45f</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p8">50</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p10">60</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p36">74</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p56">90</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c6.p66">98</nav-pointer>, <nav-pointer id="c6.p8s">92</nav-pointer>-<nav-pointer id="c6.p8adaew">93f</nav-pointer>`

Comment: @drum need to get the ascending order of the given string